# i want to access request information in mongoose and schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i want to access request information in schema in nodejs and mongoose .

i have a `BaseSchema`:

```
export function BaseSchema(schema) {
  schema.add({
    isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    owner: { type: String },
    updateDate: { type: String },
    updateBy: { type: String },
    deleteDate: { type: String },
    deleteby: { type: String },
    createDate: { type: String },
    createBy: { type: String },
  });

  schema.pre("save",async function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("BaseSchema -> req",await req)
    if (!schema.isNew) {
      this.createDate = new Date();
      this.createBy = `${req.user.firstName} ${req.user.lastName}`;
    }
    next();
  });
```

and use that in main by this way :

```
export default interface Category extends Document {
    name: string;
    icon: string;
    parentId: string;
}

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, require: true },
    icon: { type: String, require: true },
    parentId: { type: String },
}, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

CategorySchema.plugin(BaseSchema);

export const CategoryModel = model<Category>("Category", CategorySchema)
```

but in the`BaseSchema` it show me this => `req [Function (anonymous)]` .

now how can i access the `request` information ????

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking or what specific problem you're having. It doesn't seem like you want to "access the request in the model", rather that you want to store request information as part of the model's data. Are you saying you're unable to do so?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes . i want to access firstName and lastName of user in the request